# How to validate Starts with and Not Starts using Regular Expression?

Tags: regex

I was hoping to find a way to combine two regular expressions which meet the following criteria:

1. Starts with /home/
2. Does not start with /home/index

For the first case I think this works : '^/home/'

I am not sure what the regular expression for the second case should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement Negative Lookahead if supported.

```
^/home/(?!index).*$
```

Explanation:

```
^           # the beginning of the string
/home/      # '/home/'
(?!         # look ahead to see if there is not:
  index     #   'index'
)           # end of look-ahead
.*          # any character except \n (0 or more times)
$           # before an optional \n, and the end of the string
```

[**Live Demo**](http://regex101.com/r/wW5lT5/7)

Comment: i think it won't match `/home/` string.

Comment: @hwnd What if I want to make sure that the string doesn't contain a :

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: So I want to eliminate strings like /home/foo:bar

Comment: `^/home/(?!index)(?!.*:).*$`